# Running Storyboard synchronously

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, storyboard

My drawing application allows user to work with a 2-sided drawing (like the 2 sides of a paper). A button allows user to flip the drawing upside-down to work with the back side and vice versa. In the UI, the front side shows normally, whereas the back side shows in a translucent, slightly blurred form ([see example](https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=card%20transparent%20back%20side&sa=X&espv=2&biw=1680&bih=925&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&ved=0CBoQsARqFQoTCJXa78HdyMcCFcRcGgod7mYG2A#tbm=isch&q=card%20transparent%20two%20sides&imgrc=HYVx6tESdJrI5M%3A)). The underlying VM has two collection properties named `Children` and `ChildrenBack` containing the objects to display.

UI layer uses the following setup:

- Two `ItemsControl`s, one bound to `Children` and the other bound to `ChildrenBack` property.
- The `ChildrenBack` ItemsControl has its Opacity set to 0.3 to be only slightly visible.

The following `StoryBoard`s shows the flip effect:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="SB">
  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="IC" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:1.2" />
  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ICBack" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" From="-1" To="0" Duration="0:0:1.2" />
</Storyboard>
<Storyboard x:Key="SB2">
  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="IC" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:1.2" />
  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ICBack" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" From="0" To="-1" Duration="0:0:1.2" />
</Storyboard>
```

`IC` and `IC2` are the two `ItemsControl`s I mentioned. There is a property named `IsFront` that decides whether the Front or Back side are currently facing up. Setting this property automatically updates `Children` and `ChildrenBack` collections.

Now here is the problem: I need to run the first `StoryBoard` (which scales the `ItemsControl`s to 0) **before** updating the `Children` and `ChildrenBack` collections, so that the contents appear to be flipping. When the first storyboard has completed, I need to update the two collections, and then start the second animation.

The problem here is that Storyboards play asynchronously. If I set IsFront property in the VM and start first storyboard in the UI upon that change, the storyboard does not block my VM's code till the animation is complete. Instead the animation starts and immediately after that VM updates `Children` and `ChildrenBack` collections, which cripples the whole show.

I tried using `Completed` event of the first `StoryBoard` too. The problem in that case is that the View layer doesn't (and shouldn't) have any reference of the VM to ask it to update `Children` and `ChildrenBack` collections.

I tried doing `Thread.Sleep()` too, in the VM after changing `IsFront` but before changing `Children` and `ChildrenBack`, for the duration of first animation. This actually pauses the animation too. My thought was that animations would be running on a different thread, but it doesn't look like that.

So what is my way out here?

Comment: If I read your scenario correctly, I think I ran in to similar problems once. If memory serves, my way out was using the Dispatcher to "delay-set" the other related properties, giving the initial animation time to complete. Most of the time. And they were short running animations, fractions of seconds, rather than your 1.2 seconds. But perhaps this gives you something to work with.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt: Thanks for the input. As I was waiting for an answer, I continued doing my experimentation and ended up doing EXACTLY what you have mentioned. Then came back and saw your comment and said, Yeah, there are other people like me! LOL. A bundle of thanks for the input.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt: To be honest, I don't like this approach too much. It currently works and does exactly what I need, but my 6th sense tells me there should be better ways of achieving this. I'll wait for a guru's word on it.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt: Also, my actual time too is only 0.1 second, not 1.2 seconds. I had slowed down the animation just to check what was happening when.

Comment: There should (ought to?) be a better way indeed, that's why the "Most of the time" part in my comment ;) It worked in something like 95 - 99% of the cases, which, given the time constraints at the time, sufficed. But I was definitely not a happy using it :)